# How do I overlay a PNG over two videos (one video overlays another) in one command using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I'm a new user of FFmpeg, and I want to insert a logo on two videos (one video overlay another) with one command.

For example, I have a background video (1), a video in scaling (2) and a logo (3P, and I want to create a video that has “3 on 2 on 1” in one command.

In normal, I have to do step by step: scale video (2), then overlay this video on background video (3), and finally overlay the logo (1) on top. I think these steps can decrease the final video quality due to re-encode 3 times.

---

1st step:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=1280:720 -c:a copy output1.mp4
```

2nd step:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i background.mp4 -i output1.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=1280:720[inner];[0][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -y output2.mp4
```

3rd step:

```
ffmpeg -i output2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable=not(between'(t\,10\,15)')" -codec:a copy -preset medium output3.mp4
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Use this command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i background.mp4 -i input.mp4 -i logo.png
-filter_complex "[1]scale=1280:720[inner];[0][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[vid];
                 [vid][2]overlay=10:10:enable='not(between(t\,10\,15))'[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -y output.mp4
```